# Thread _ Jframe Java

Tags: java, multithreading, swing

I have a Thread launched when a Jboutton listener event . The thread code is huge and I wish when The user close the Jframe the thread continue to run until finishing (even the Jframe is closed ). What Can I do ?

Comment: We need a bit of code to help u. And you should show what you have tried so far.

Comment: Post [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Change the defaultCloseOperation from EXIT_ON_CLOSE to DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE.

Comment: See [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9554657/418556)

Answer (score 0):

Setting default close operation of frame from `JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE` to `JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE` seems to do exactly what you want.

Demo:

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
JButton button = new JButton("click me");

//frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
frame.setSize(100,100);
frame.add(button);

button.addActionListener((listener)->{
    new Thread(()->{
        System.out.println("Thread started");
        for (int i=0; i<10; i++){
            System.out.println(i);
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Thread ended");
    }).start();
});
frame.setVisible(true);
```

If you click button and close frame you will see that thread created by button will still be working. Application will close after all threads will finish their tasks.